# Unable to encrypt JSON via private key.pem

Tags: python, json, ssl, encryption

I'm working with Passbase a KYC provider and it's required to encrypt the metadata using pem 4096-bit certificate. Details here: https://docs.passbase.com/server/metadata-encryption#encrypt-data-in-backend

Using their examples I can generate a private and public key. The public key is shared with them.

```
openssl genrsa -out ~/passbase-test-private-key.pem 4096
openssl rsa -in ~/passbase-test-private-key.pem -out ~/passbase-test-public-key.pub -pubout
```

This is their sample code to encrypt data

```
import base64
import subprocess
import tempfile
metadata = bytearray('{"foo": "bar"}', 'utf-8')
with open("~/passbase-test-private-key.pem", "rb") as f:
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        "openssl rsautl -sign -inkey " + f.name,
        shell=True,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input=metadata)
    encrypted_metadata = base64.b64encode(stdout)
```

Since our pem certificate will be not in local but in Google Secret manager I tried the following. For the test, I added the private key info to .env

```
def encrypt_metadata(data):

    metadata = bytearray(str(data), 'utf-8')

    ENCRYPTION_KEY = os.environ.get('private_rsa_passbase_key')
    
    #encrypt metadata
    p = subprocess.Popen(ENCRYPTION_KEY,
        shell=True,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input=metadata)
    encrypted_metadata = base64.b64encode(stdout)

    print (p,stdout,stderr,encrypted_metadata)

    return encrypted_metadata
```

I'm unable to generate encrypted metadata and this is what is being printed:

```
<Popen: returncode: 2 args: ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'N...> b'' b'/bin/sh: --: invalid option\nUsage:\t/bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] ...\n\t/bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...\nGNU long options:\n\t--debug\n\t--debugger\n\t--dump-po-strings\n\t--dump-strings\n\t--help\n\t--init-file\n\t--login\n\t--noediting\n\t--noprofile\n\t--norc\n\t--posix\n\t--protected\n\t--rcfile\n\t--restricted\n\t--verbose\n\t--version\n\t--wordexp\nShell options:\n\t-irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option\t\t(invocation only)\n\t-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option\n' b''
```

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use OpenSSL through subprocess? [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/) has an RSA module with a much better interface.

Comment: Yes, as previous comment says, for things like that you should not fork out to execute a command, as this has various from bad to extremely dangerous consequences both on performances and security. Also you do `subprocess.Popen(ENCRYPTION_KEY` which is wrong, the first argument to `Popen` should be the command to run, and then parameters. You completely removed that from the example given (which is what the error message tells you: the shell does not understand what command you want to run... because you just didn't specify it)

Comment: Yes makes sense. If you could provide an answer using the RSA module that solves the above, I can accept the answer

Comment: For pure Python versions you can look at https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#signing-and-verifying-signatures  the PyOpenSSL module that sits on top of cryptography module with an higher level interface.

Comment: The posted Python code doesn't adhere to the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 standard because it signs the data *directly* and not the DER encoding of the *DigestInfo* value. Most Python libraries stick to the standard (recognizable by the digest to be specified alongside the hash). However, the format used is that simple (s. [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-rsautl.html), sec. *Examples*) that it can easily be implemented by oneself (s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72703671)). Otherwise, the only option is probably to call OpenSSL from Python (with the described fix).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a step in the right direction:
The terminology used here is wrong, as one does not encrypt with a private key. If you "encrypt" with a private key, what you get is a signature. This signature can be verified using the public key. Instead, one would encrypt with a public key and decrypt with a private key.

In your test using the environment variable, as far as I see, the subprocess does miss the command parameter. Instead you are passing the key as command.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Yes I did find it strange but they wrote "The metaData object requires an encrypted JSON string via the private key encoded in base64" and asked me to upload the public key to their dashboard. Would have expected the opposite. True will try to change the command parameter

Comment: `openssl rsautl -sign` yes `-sign` is really just to sign... the documentation says it clearly: "-sign
           Sign the input data and output the signed result. This requires an RSA private key."

Comment: "and asked me to upload the public key to their dashboard. Would have expected the opposite. " In very broad summary: anything "encrypted" by one of the key can only be decrypted by the other. Hence if you encrypt something by priviate key, it is obviously not confidential as the public key can decrypt it and "everyone" should have the public key, so what you do it is more a signature. On the opposite if "anyone" encrypts with the public key (which is ... public) then only the owner of the private key can decrypt, so that is the strict definition of "encryption" as in "undecipherable".